# Price and weight input issue in Magento 2 backend

Tags: magento

I've installed new Magento 2 CE 2.x and use Porto theme. Every time I input price for product, for eg: 1946000 and save. The page get reloaded and show "1.946.000" for the price, but if I click save one more time, the price is changed to "2".

I have the same problem with weight.

My Magento installation is clean and I haven't touched the core yet.

Comment: What version of Magento 2 are you using, and what is your store setup like? (assuming not USD/GBP here)

Comment: I'm using 2.1.2, country is Vietnam, locale is vi_VN, base & display currency is Vietnam Dong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?